# How to run cordova-applications with visual-studio 2015 (win10)?

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, ripple

It seems like i cant use any method of running cordova's apps.
I instaled emualtor for android:
https://www.visualstudio.com/pl-pl/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx
But vs2015 dosent seems to "see" it - no new options, and whenever i try use "android emulator" vs15 start other - from android studio.  (Currently i'm trying to reinstall from vs2015 "upate" option)
I tried useing ripple with chrome, but even newly created "empty cordova application" just crash, or wont even lunch.
I already tried:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file
(Similar fix also recomended here)
But error with "MySQL" still appers when i try to use "Device" option to run it.
Already moved config.xml to app's folder.

Comment: Hi Asker. Sorry to hear about your trouble. I'd like to help you but I'm not quite sure where to start. Could you contact us at vscordovatools@microsoft.com so we can help you over email? It sounds like the emulators aren't installed through Visual Studio, but I'd also like to understand why Ripple is crashing on you. [Disclosure: I work for Microsoft]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing system and goign back to windows 7 resolved it.